# is it a Markov Chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Example:

"When rolling regular fair six-sided die repeatedly, the number
shown."

The answer I was given was, yes, it is a a Markov Chain.But according to my understanding,  a Markov Chain is something like you only need to know the current state to predict the future stat. In this rolling dice example, even the current state cannot be used to predict the future state?

Comment: It is true that the current state cannot be used to predict the future state, but that is not required of a Markov chain.  Future states just can't depend on the history *other* than the current state, and that is still true here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's still a markov chain. All you need for a markov chain is the condition that

$$P(X_i=v_i| X_{1} =v_1\land X_2=v_2\land\cdots\land X_{i-1}=v_{i-1} = P(X_i=v_i|X_{i-1}=v_{i-1}) $$

and this condition is clearly satisfied here (since both sides of the equation are equal to $\frac16$).

---

Intuitively, a Markov chain is

> any sequence of events where, given one state, you can calculate the probabilities of the next state.

Note that this is **not the same as**

> any sequence of events where you can calculate the probabilities of the next state *from* the current state.